# Unable to Access RabbitMQ Web Interface

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04, rabbitmqctl

I have built RabbitMQ 3.7.3 from source on Ubuntu 16.04 using the following steps:

1)Installed Erlang 20.0, Elixir 1.6.1 and hex 0.17.3.

2)    `git clone https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server.git && 
   cd rabbitmq-server/ &&
   git checkout v3.7.3 &&
   make all`

The build was successful and I'm able to start the server using `make run-broker` and also can see server status using `rabbitmqctl status` but I can't enable the management plugin as its not found in the source. Is it built/downloaded during the build? How do I get and enable the Management plugin in order to access the UI?

I'm following http://www.rabbitmq.com/build-server.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: Why not just download the latest build, which includes the plug-in?

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management

Answer (score 1):

As theMayer said, you really should be using a package. To build from source *and* have plugins available, use this project:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella

The following command will run the broker with the management plugin enabled:

```
make PLUGINS='rabbitmq_management run-broker
```

Comment: My requirement is to install latest v3.7.3, but this link has only till v3.6.14

Answer (score 0):

The source for the RabbitMQ Management Plug-in is located on GitHub, at the following location:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management

There are guides available as well for building, and I'm not sure about installing it as I've only ever used the pre-packaged builds.

Comment: yes but how to use this source with my Rabbitmq setup?

Answer (score 0):

By default RabbitMQ web management console runs on port 15672. So you will need to allow this port through UFW firewall. By default UFW firewall is disabled in Ubuntu 16.04, so you will need to enable it first. You can enable UFW filrewall with the following command:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Once UFW is enabled, allow port 15672 using the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 15672
```